# Getting errors in java program to write to Kinesis Firehose stream

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to just write some data from an API (google stocks/finance API) to my AWS Firehose stream. I already downloaded and installed the AWS plugin on Eclipse, setup my Firehose stream on AWS, and everything seems to be setup correctly. Am encountering some problems, though. The following line seems to be deprecated...I tried different variations from Amazon's SDK, but I can't seem to get the correct code.

> AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient firehoseClient = new
>   AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient(credentials);

Next, I'm getting some errors with the following. The specific error is, "*The method setRecord(Record) is undefined for the type PutRecordRequest,"* even though I took it directly from Amazon's API reference.

> request.setRecord(record);
>
> firehoseClient.putRecord(request);

Also getting an error on the second line above: *"The method putRecord(com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.model.PutRecordRequest) in the type AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient is not applicable for the arguments (com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest)"*

```
package com.amazonaws.samples;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;

import com.amazonaws.*;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesis;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.interfaces.IRecordProcessorFactory;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisClientLibConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.model.PutRecordBatchRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.model.Record;

public class FirehoseExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWSCredentials credentials = null;

        try {
            credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
                    + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
                    + "location (/Users/elybenari/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
        }

        AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient firehoseClient = new AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient(credentials);
        PutRecordRequest request = new PutRecordRequest();
        request.setStreamName("project-stream");

        Record record = new Record();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20*60; i++){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NASDAQ:AMZN");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);  
                }
                reader.close();

                System.out.println(response.toString().replace("\n", "").replaceAll(" ", ""));
                System.out.println("****\n");

                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(response.toString().replace("\n", "").replaceAll(" ", "").getBytes());
                record.setData(buff);

                request.setRecord(record);

                firehoseClient.putRecord(request);

                Thread.sleep(2000);


            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   

    }




    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you've included some classes from Kinesis, *not* Kinesis Firehose, Java package. For e.g., you've used:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest;
```

Whereas, you should've used:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesisfirehose.model.PutRecordRequest;
```

Kinesis, Kinesis Firehose and Kinesis Analytics are different services, even though they fall under one umbrella of streaming services on AWS. Consequently, they have different package namespaces in the Java SDK. If you start from the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), you'll reach the correct Java SDK reference [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesisfirehose/model/PutRecordRequest.html).

**EDIT**: To answer your other question: yes, the following is deprecated:

```
AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient firehoseClient = new AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient(credentials);
```

You should instead use the following:

```
 AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient firehoseClient = AmazonKinesisFirehoseClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();
```

Refer to the official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesisfirehose/AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.html) on how to correctly initialize AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient.

Comment: Thank you...That was very helpful!! One last question, do you know what the correct, non-depracated way is to write this line?         AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient firehoseClient = new AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient(credentials);

Comment: Updated the answer. Don't forget to *accept* the answer if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the response...When I add the code you gave me exactly as is (except I change the credentials), I get the following error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from AmazonKinesisFirehose to AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient"

Comment: Should I cast the second part to a AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient?

Comment: Can you check the AWS documentation? I don't have my laptop for couple of days, so can't check myself. The documentation should answer your question.

Comment: Oh my god Thank you. @ketanvijayvargiya